# Image dont appear

Tags: java, android, xml

Thanks in advance,
I have an image, and I want to show it when my **contatore** is more then 10.
But it doesn't appear.

```
ImageView immagine;
immagine = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nello);
immagine.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
...
contatore++;
display.setText("Il totale è: "+ contatore);

if (contatore >10)
{
    immagine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}`
```

Comment: what's the event that triggers this piece of code?

Comment: add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
contatore++;
}
});

Comment: do you have a button that when clicked increments contatore? reading the question it's really hard to understand what you are trying todo...

Comment: Yes, i've a button then increments contatore

Comment: ok, could you post all relevant code?

Comment: JAVA : http://pastebin.com/qfaaGNxS
XML : http://pastebin.com/GyNQcjNE

Comment: your test should be in your onClick listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    contatore++;
    display.setText("Il totale è: "+ contatore);

    if (contatore > 10) {
        immagine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this check at every click,
contatore's value is checked only at onCreate
this must go inside every OnClickListener

```
if (contatore >10)    
        immagine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```